# one pic error!

Tags: python, tensorflow, 深層学習

以下のサンプルスクリプトを実行しようとしていますが、トレーニング中の画像を出力するタイミングで、「one pic error!...」と表示され、画像が出力されません。
https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow

サンプルスクリプトではErrorが発生した関係で、以下2行の変更を加えているので
この部分が被疑かと思っているのですがどうすれば解決するのでしょうか。

```
im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(np.asarray(x[j:j+crop_h, i:i+crop_w])))
return cropped_image
```

---

**utils.py (変更前)**

```
def center_crop(x, crop_h, crop_w,
                resize_h=64, resize_w=64):
  if crop_w is None:
    crop_w = crop_h
  h, w = x.shape[:2]
  j = int(round((h - crop_h)/2.))
  i = int(round((w - crop_w)/2.))
  im = Image.fromarray(x[j:j+crop_h, i:i+crop_w])
  return np.array(im.resize([resize_h, resize_w], PIL.Image.BILINEAR))

def transform(image, input_height, input_width, 
              resize_height=64, resize_width=64, crop=True):
  if crop:
    cropped_image = center_crop(
      image, input_height, input_width, 
      resize_height, resize_width)
  else:
    im = Image.fromarray(image[j:j+crop_h, i:i+crop_w])
  return np.array(im.resize([resize_h, resize_w], PIL.Image.BILINEAR))/127.5 - 1.
```

**utils.py (変更後)**

```
def center_crop(x, crop_h, crop_w,
                resize_h=64, resize_w=64):
  if crop_w is None:
    crop_w = crop_h
  h, w = x.shape[:2]
  j = int(round((h - crop_h)/2.))
  i = int(round((w - crop_w)/2.))
  im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(np.asarray(x[j:j+crop_h, i:i+crop_w])))
  return np.array(im.resize([resize_h, resize_w], PIL.Image.BILINEAR))

def transform(image, input_height, input_width, 
              resize_height=64, resize_width=64, crop=True):
  if crop:
    cropped_image = center_crop(
      image, input_height, input_width, 
      resize_height, resize_width)
    return cropped_image
  else:
    im = Image.fromarray(image[j:j+crop_h, i:i+crop_w])
    return np.array(im.resize([resize_h, resize_w], PIL.Image.BILINEAR))/127.5 - 1.
```

Comment: `transform` 関数内に `i`, `j`, `crop_h` と `crop_w` という変数が使われていますが、これらはどこで定義されているのでしょう？

Comment: 確認してみたところ確かに定義されていないように見えます。ただこのコードだとelseに入ることがないので特に関連性はなさそうです。

Comment: こちらで試してみると、[imread 関数](https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow/blob/master/utils.py#L49) の戻り値が `astype(np.float)` となっていて、`np.float` 型の場合には `center_crop` 関数内の `Image.fromarray()` でエラーになります(エラーメッセージは`"Cannot handle this data type"`)。RGB データなので `np.float` ではなく `np.uint8` が適切かと思います。また、`from PIL import Image` としてインポートしていますので、`PIL.Image.BILINEAR` は `Image.BILINEAR` としないとエラーになります。

Comment: ちなみにエラーメッセージ `one pic error...` に関してですが、[ここ](https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow/blob/master/model.py#L326)で表示されています。`try` 〜 `except` でスタックトレースを表示させる様にしておけばエラーが発生しても原因を調べやすくなるのですが……

Comment: 細かくご説明いただきありがとうございます。スタックトレースを使用して解決することができました。